# Need to match only second occurrence from a packet in Regex

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I have a scenario with the packet above and I want to match in regex only the Second field (Then ill replace only this value without break the packet), I already done the first value with this regex and need for the second and third.

```
/([^/]+)[a-z]
```

**Packet:**

> GET /First_Random/Second_Random/Third_Random/search_results.php
>   HTTP/1.1

Thanks.

[First Part Regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKkyl.png)

Comment: you only want to find and change Second_Random and rest stays same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could capture the first part in a group, and match the second and the third part using negated character classes `[^`

In the replacement make use of the first capturing group (usually `$1` or `\1`) followed by your replacement divided by a forward slash

```
^([^/]*/[^/]+/)[^/]+/[^/]+
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^/]*/[^/]+/` Match the beginning of the string and the first part till the `/`
- `)` Close group
- `[^/]+/[^/]+` Match the second and the third part divided by `/`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Bd5gx/1)

An example of a possible replacement format

```
$1SECOND/THIRD
```